# Unable extract text from html page in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am very new to web scraping. I read about BeautifulSoup and tried to use it. But I am not able to extract text with given class name "company-desc-and-sort-container". I am not even able to extract the title from html page. This is the code which I tried:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= 'http://fortune.com/best-companies/'    
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

#print soup.prettify()[0:1000]
print soup.find_all("title")

letters = soup.find_all("div", class_="company-desc-and-sort-container")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 print soup.find_all("title")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: what's your beautifulsoup version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are using `BeautifulSoup` version 3**, which is not only maintained anymore, but also *does not have the `find_all()` method*. And, since the dot notation is used as a shortcut to `find()`, `BeautifulSoup` tries to find element with "find_all" tag name which results into `None`. Then, it would execute `None("title")` which results into:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Upgrade to `BeautifulSoup` version 4, replace:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Make sure to have `beautifulsoup4` package installed:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find_all("title")
```

Is  not finding a title tag and returning "none".  Also the "find_all" method will return a list if it does find something  and you will get a different  error. You can't print a list.   Use just the "find" method. That will do d the first title tag.

Then does the html page even have a title tag?  Search, and only print if not none.